# Links sometimes not working with Docker-compose version 2

Tags: docker-compose

Considering the following (working) docker-compose.yaml file:

```
nsqlookupd:
  image: nsqio/nsq
  ports:
    - "4160:4160"
    - "4161:4161"
  command: /nsqlookupd

nsqd:
  image: nsqio/nsq
  ports:
    - "4150"
    - "4151"
  links:
    - nsqlookupd:nsqlookupd
  command: /nsqd --lookupd-tcp-address=nsqlookupd:4160

nsqadmin:
  image: nsqio/nsq
  ports:
    - "4171:4171"
  links:
    - nsqlookupd:nsqlookupd
  command: /nsqadmin --lookupd-http-address=nsqlookupd:4161
```

If I update the format to version "2" (just adding the 2 first lines):

```
version: "2"
services:
  nsqlookupd:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    ports:
      - "4160:4160"
      - "4161:4161"
    command: /nsqlookupd

  nsqd:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    ports:
      - "4150"
      - "4151"
    links:
      - nsqlookupd:nsqlookupd
    command: /nsqd --lookupd-tcp-address=nsqlookupd:4160

  nsqadmin:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    ports:
      - "4171:4171"
    links:
      - nsqlookupd:nsqlookupd
    command: /nsqadmin --lookupd-http-address=nsqlookupd:4161
```

It doesn't work anymore, and I don't see why.
By not working, I mean the services can't create tcp connections:

```
nsqd_1       | [nsqd] 2016/04/02 16:10:47.511813 LOOKUPD(nsqlookupd:4160): ERROR PING - dial tcp: i/o timeout

nsqadmin_1   | [nsqadmin] 2016/04/02 16:10:51.865724 ERROR: failed to get topics - Failed to query any nsqlookupd: Get http://nsqlookupd:4161/topics: dial tcp: i/o timeout
```

From the linked containers, I can ping the other services (ie: from nsqadmin, I can ping nsqlookupd

Any idea?

Comment: You may need to add a delay before attempting to connect to anything. Now that links are backed by an embedded dns server, the hostname is not necessarily available immediately.

Comment: I don't see the point to use the version "2" then :)

Comment: If I have to add some messy/word-around configuration, with things only related to issues docker-compose _could_ have, it's not worth it... Especially if it was working fine with the previous version :)

Comment: It's not related to issues only compose would have. It's related to real productions issues: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/